# Unknown column 'BookId' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build an `ASP.NET Core` Web API with `MySQL` on the basis of the tutorial [Creating a Database with Code First in EF Core](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html)

I've deleted and commented some code to localize the reason of the error.

This is my class book:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id {  get; set; }        
    public string Title { get; set; }    
    public string Author { get; set; }    
    public int Pages { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }     
}
```

And this is my class Review:

```
   public class Review
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Creator { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }        
       //public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
   }
```

LibraryContext.cs

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; } <-- when I comment this line the error disappears
    public DbSet<Review> Review { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {        
    optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine).UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=books;user=???;password=???");        
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using (var context = new LibraryContext())
{
    var review = new Review
    {
       Id = 3
    };

    context.Review.Add(review);
    context.SaveChanges(); <-- throws the error
}
```

When I comment the line `public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }` in `LibraryContext.cs` the error doesn't appear and I can save the data in the database. But I need this line. What can I do to make the error disappear?

Comment: Are your migrations up to date?

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thanks for the hint. There was a FK missing because I've created the tables manually. When I let it create by the code it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `FK` missing because I've created the tables manually. When I let them create by code it works.

In table reviews there must be a `FK` `BookId`.